# Marshalling CDATA elements with CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS adds carriage return characters

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cdata, line-endings

I'm working on an application that exports and imports data from / to a DB. The format of the data extract is XML and I'm using JAXB for the serialization / (un)marshalling. I want some elements to be marshalled as CDATA elements and am using [this solution](http://javacoalface.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/outputting-cdata-sections-with-jaxb.html) which sets `OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS` to the `Transformer` properties.

So far this was working quite well, but now I came to a field in the DB that itself contains an XML string, which I also would like to place inside of a CDATA element. Now, for some reason the `Transformer` is now adding some unnecessary carriage return characters (`\r`) to each line end, so that the output looks like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
  private static final String IDENT_LENGTH = "3";
  private static final String CDATA_XML_ELEMENTS = "text definition note expression mandatoryExpression optionalExpression settingsXml";

  public static void marshall(final Object rootObject, final Schema schema, final Writer writer) throws Exception {
    final JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(rootObject.getClass());
    final Document document = createDocument();
    final Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.setSchema(schema);
    marshaller.marshal(rootObject, document);
    createTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));
  }

  private static Document createDocument() throws ParserConfigurationException {
    // the DocumentBuilderFactory is actually being hold in a singleton
    final DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    return builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
  }

  private static Transformer createTransformer() throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError {
    // the TransformerFactory is actually being hold in a singleton
    final TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    final Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, CDATA_XML_ELEMENTS);
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", IDENT_LENGTH);
    return transformer;
  }
```

I'm passing a `FileWriter` to the `marshall` method.

My annotated model class looks like this:

```
@XmlType
@XmlRootElement
public class DashboardSettings {

  @XmlElement
  private String settingsXml;

  public String getSettingsXml() {
    return settingsXml;
  }

  public void setSettingsXml(final String settingsXml) {
    this.settingsXml = settingsXml;
  }
}
```

**NOTE:**

The XML string coming from the DB has Windows style line endings, i.e. `\r` and `\n`. I have the feeling that JAXB expects currently Linux style input (i. e. only `\n`) and is therefore adding a `\r` character because I'm currently running on a Windows machine. So the question is actually, what's the best way to solve this? Is there any parameter I can pass to control the line ending characters when marshalling? Or should I convert the line endings to Linux style prior marshalling? How will my program behave on different platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac OS)?

I don't necessarily need a platform independent solution, it's OK if the output is in Windows, Linux or whatever style. What I want to avoid is the combination `\r\r\n` as shown in the above screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this question is pretty old, but I ran into a similar problem, so maybe an answer can help someone else.

It seems to be an issue with CDATA sections. In my case, I was using the `createCDATASection` method to create them. When the code was running on a Windows machine, an additional `CR` was added, as in your example.

I've tried a bunch of things to solve this "cleanly", to no avail.

In my project, the XML document was then exported to a string to POST to a Linux server. So once the string was generated, I just removed the `CR` characters, leaving only the `LF`:

```
myXmlString.replaceAll("\\r", "");
```

I might not be an appropriate solution for the specific question, but once again, it may help you (or someone else) find a solution.

**Note:** I'm stuck with Java 7 for this specific project, so it may have been fixed in a more recent version.