# Java Transformer How to keep xml structure inside a CDATA

Tags: java, xml, cdata, removing-whitespace, transformer-model

When I try to transform my document using the **javax.xml.transform.Transformer**, the API is inserting some spaces between tags inside of CDATASection.

Not sure why, I'm already using the output property **INDENT** as **"no"**.

---

I want this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <infoDoc>
        <xml1><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<el1>
    <Header>
        <Success>false</Success>
    </Header>
    <Detail>
        <Key>
            <Number>4721</Number>
        </Key>
    </Detail>
</el1>]]></xml1>
    </infoDoc>
</root>
```

---

Or this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <infoDoc>
        <xml1><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><el1><Header><Success>false</Success></Header><Detail><Key><Number>4721</Number></Key></Detail></el1>]]></xml1>
    </infoDoc>
</root>
```

---

But I'm receiving this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><infoDoc><xml1><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<el1>

    <Header>

        <Success>false</Success>

    </Header>

    <Detail>

        <Key>

            <Number>4721</Number>

        </Key>

    </Detail>

</el1>]]></xml1></infoDoc></root>
```

---

Is there another property that do this?

Or another API, that can do it right?

**EDIT:**
I'm using as follow:

```
...
final Element xml1 = doc.createElement("xml1");
final CDATASection xml1Content = doc.createCDATASection(new String(bytes, Charset.forName(encoding)));
xml1.appendChild(xml1Content);
infoDoc.appendChild(xml1);
...


...
final DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, encoding);
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
transformer.transform(source, result);
...
```

Comment: Maybe just a typo? It's indent, not ident.

Comment: I'm using **OutputKeys.INDENT**, just wrong typed on the post.

Comment: are you sure the problem isn't happening before the transform?  your output document doesn't have indenting for the xml document itself (outside the cdata section) which seems to imply that the problem may be occurring elsewhere.  did you verify the data is not indented before you call transform?

Comment: I'm sure that is the transformer that include whitespaces into cdata content.

But not sure why.

Comment: The CDATA section is supposed to contain the original text verbatim, i.e. you should either expect the first result or the second.
If the original text had line breaks, it seems that your transformation doubles only line breaks, nothing else.
Could it be that the original text has line breaks which are the 'wrong' style for your system, e.g. CRLF on UNIX?

Comment: Maybe, I'm running on windows.
Java Transformer's method does Unix line break?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Marshalling CDATA elements with CDATA\_SECTION\_ELEMENTS adds carriage return characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483165/marshalling-cdata-elements-with-cdata-section-elements-adds-carriage-return-char)